# Error: Type 'FormDataEntryValue' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'File' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have this data that I get from the `formData` and I want it to pass for the function for sending an email.

Error:

```
Type 'FormDataEntryValue' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.ts(2322)
definitions.ts(119, 3): The expected type comes from property 'lastName' which is declared here on type 'InvoiceEmailData'
(property) lastName: string | null
No quick fixes available
```

Error occurs on the `InvoiceEmailData` for `firstName`, `lastName`, and `remarks`.

```
'use server'


export default async function addCustomerOrder(cart: any, total: number, formData: FormData): Promise<{ message: string }> {     
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const supabase = createServerActionClient({ cookies: () => cookieStore })

    let order_id;

    try{
  
        const firstName = formData.get('firstName')
        const lastName = formData.get('lastName')
        const remarks = formData.get('remarks')
             //rest of the codes...

            //sending an email
            try{

                const emailData: InvoiceEmailData = {
                    firstName: firstName || "",
                    lastName: lastName || "",
                    order_id: order_id || "",
                    cart: cart,
                    total: total,
                    remarks
                  };

                  const res = await sendMailFunction({
                    to: "ravenousred18@gmail.com",
                    name: `${emailData.firstName} ${emailData.lastName}`,
                    subject: `New Order Placed ${emailData.order_id}`,
                    body: generateInvoiceEmailBody(emailData),
                  });

        

                console.log(res, "email sent")
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err, "email error")
            }

        
            return {  message: `Succesfully added the data` }
    }catch(e){
        return {message: "Failed to submit the form."}
    }

}


export async function sendMailFunction ({to, name, subject, body}: {to: string, name: string; subject: string; body: string}) {
    await sendMail({
        to: to,
        name: name,
        subject: subject,
        body: `${body}`
    })
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as we see from documentation, `get` method return `string | File`, it means you should explicitly coerce type to string to get your field values like this`

`const firstName = formData.get('firstName') as string`

[type definition for FormDataEntryValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXFov.png)

[Documentation](https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Web/API/FormData/get#:%7E:text=Additional%20Resources-,FormData,-.get())

Comment: I am having the same issue. Yet I am only receiving `string` from my form. I know this is the solution, but it seems redundant to do string.string() on each value since they are already strings. Have you seen any alternatives?

Comment: Sorry, can't give suggestion other than this